# Сортировка массива по значениям ключей объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Ребята, нужна ваша помощь. Я застрял. **Два вопроса:**

1. Есть массив вида:

   ```
    const countries = ["Turkey", "Brazil", "Germany", "Canada", "Norway", "Netherlands", "Denmark", "United Kingdom", "Iran", "France", "Denmark", "France", "France", "Denmark", "Brazil", "United States", "Brazil", "United States", "United Kingdom", "Denmark", "Germany"]
   ```

Нужно сделать сортировку в объект массивов по национальности:

```
const nationalities = {american: [], australian: [], brazilian: [], british: [], canadian: [], danish: [], dutch: [], finnish: [],
        french: [], german: [], iranian: [], irish: [], newZealander: [], norwegian: [], spanish: [], swiss: [], turkish: []};
```

получить объект:

```
const nationalities = {american:['United States', 'United States'], australian:['Australian'], brazilian:['Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil'], british:['United Kingdom']...}
```

2. На основании пользовательского ввода вывести только нужный массив(массивы) из объекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример:

Выбран 'American' -> показать только массив american остальные скрыть,

Выбрано 'British', 'Canadian' -> показать только british и canadian

Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**касательно задачи 1:**

для начала у вас долен быть словарь соответствий:

```
dict = {
    "united states": "american",
    "russia": "russian"
};
```

затем вы проходите по массиву `countries` и проверяете соответствия:

```
let nationalities = {};
for (country of countries) {
    const nation = dict[country];
    nationalities[nation].push(nation);
}
```

только надо добавить соответствующие проверки на отсутствие данных в словаре и массиве

**касательно задачи 2:**

примените фильтр в массиву `nationalities`, не совсем только понял - нужно по части от слова искать или доступны слова целиком

хотя если `nationalities` не объект, то можно просто пройтись по элементам и сформировать новый массив

```
let filtered_nationalities = {};

for (nation of Object.keys(nationalities)) {
    if (choice.includes(nation)) {
        filtered_nationalities[nation] = nationalities[nation];
    }
}
```

что-то на подобии этого

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Вы мне очень помогли!